# Electronic article surveillance sensor or alternative

Tags: sensor, wireless, proximity

I'm looking for some sort of sensor for detecting certain object crossing a line or passing a gate. The sensor must detect an object from at least 1.5 m distance.

I tried to use a laser sensor but it detects just any object, not a certain one. I think that something like an Electronic Article Surveillance sensor (Acousto-Magnetic 58 kHz) with a tag will do the job, but I couldn't find any schematics examples for it. Maybe there are some alternative solutions for my problem.

The object is a zip-line passenger, there can be additional equipment (tag) on him. The tag should preferably be passive, but it can be battery powered if that makes an easier solution possible.

Comment: Hello and welcome.  You'll gert much better answers if you give more information in your question.  What is the object you want to detect?  Can you put equipment on it?  Does it have power?  Daytime?  Nighttime?  How fast is it moving?

Comment: The same system they use for anti-theft in most supermarkets would do the job. I think that's what you're talking about with the acousto-magnetic thing. You can just buy those.

Comment: If it's a person on a zip line, can you put a laser on one side and sensor on the other?  What other objects might be mistaken for the target person?

Answer (score 0):

When thinking in terms of electronics searching for some object - you need to think that the hardware is trying to discriminate an object by some physical parameters that describe that object from some "clutter".

You could make it easier for the hardware to detect relevant objects by tagging them beforehand making sure the tag has strong enough features that can be distinguished easily(for example some kind of ultrasonic transmitter can be easily distinguished from people speech because our voice is sonic)

You could also try and characterize your object in other ways like shape, electromagnetic behavior(like radars and metal detectors), colors, patterns etc.

Hope this provided you with some ideas to create your project

Answer (score 0):

This would be a good application for machine vision. This could be done economically on a small platform like Raspberry Pi. More here: https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/raspberry-pi-facial-recognition